# bootstrap 3 carousel shrinks in height when cycling

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

As i said while the carousel cycles the height of the elements inside it become smaller until it reaches the next frame. I someone could shed some light upon this issue i would greatly appreciate it, it's something that just has to be fixed and it's driving me nuts an all others sorts of edible things.

The html :

```
               <div id="shop-crsl-1" class="carousel slide shop-crsl hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel">

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="shop-col-item">
                                    <div class="photo">
                                        <img src="images/sc/shop-crsl-1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="price">
                                                <h5>Casual Suit</h5>
                                                <h5 class="main-text-color">$199.99</h5>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="rating">
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="btns clear-left">
                                            <p class="btn-add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#">Add to cart</a></p>
                                            <p class="btn-details"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#">More details</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="shop-col-item">
                                    <div class="photo">
                                        <img src="images/sc/shop-crsl-2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="price">
                                                <h5>Night Suit</h5>
                                                <h5 class="main-text-color">$249.99</h5>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="rating">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="btns clear-left">
                                            <p class="btn-add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#">Add to cart</a></p>
                                            <p class="btn-details"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#">More details</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="shop-col-item">
                                    <div class="photo">
                                        <img src="images/sc/shop-crsl-3.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="price">
                                                <h5>Elegant Suit</h5>
                                                <h5 class="main-text-color">$149.99</h5>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="rating">
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="btns clear-left">
                                            <p class="btn-add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#">Add to cart</a></p>
                                            <p class="btn-details"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#">More details</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="shop-col-item">
                                    <div class="photo">
                                        <img src="images/sc/shop-crsl-1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="price">
                                                <h5>Super-Casual Suit</h5>
                                                <h5 class="main-text-color">$199.99</h5>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="rating">
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="btns clear-left">
                                            <p class="btn-add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#">Add to cart</a></p>
                                            <p class="btn-details"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#">More details</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="shop-col-item">
                                    <div class="photo">
                                        <img src="images/sc/shop-crsl-2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="price">
                                                <h5>Super-Night Suit</h5>
                                                <h5 class="main-text-color">$249.99</h5>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="rating">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="btns clear-left">
                                            <p class="btn-add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#">Add to cart</a></p>
                                            <p class="btn-details"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#">More details</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="shop-col-item">
                                    <div class="photo">
                                        <img src="images/sc/shop-crsl-3.png" class="img-responsive" alt="a">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="info">
                                        <div>
                                            <div class="price">
                                                <h5>Super-Elegant Suit</h5>
                                                <h5 class="main-text-color">$149.99</h5>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="rating">
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="main-text-color fa fa-star"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="btns clear-left">
                                            <p class="btn-add"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="#">Add to cart</a></p>
                                            <p class="btn-details"><i class="fa fa-list"></i><a href="#">More details</a></p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <!-- Controls -->
                    <div class="controls">
                        <a class="left fa fa-chevron-left" href="#shop-crsl-1" data-slide="prev"> </a>
                        <a class="right fa fa-chevron-right" href="#shop-crsl-1" data-slide="next"> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

beloved css

```
.shop-crsl {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    padding: 0 15px;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
}

.shop-crsl .controls a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 53px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -30px;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: all 0.35s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.shop-crsl .controls a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.shop-crsl .controls .left {
    left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-right: 3px;
}

.shop-crsl .controls .right {
    right: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 3px;
}

.shop-col-item:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.shop-promo {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.shop-promo h3 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.shop-promo .title {
    font-size: 42px;
    line-height: 48px;
    padding: 12px 0;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
}

.shop-promo .button {
    margin: 24px 0;
}

.shop-promo p {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.shop-col-item {
}

.shop-col-item .photo {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.shop-col-item .photo img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.shop-col-item .info {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.shop-col-item .price {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.shop-col-item .price h5 {
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}

.shop-col-item .rating {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 52px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 52px;
}

.shop-col-item .btn-add {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.shop-col-item .btn-details {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.shop-col-item .btn-details .fa-list {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}

.shop-col-item .btns p {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.shop-col-item .btns p i {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? if your telling,the carousel is becoming smaller when u resize the screen,its being responsive for different screen sizes.

Comment: i have solved it. as i said it became smaller in height while cycling through it

Comment: I had the same issue, `.carousel-inner>.active { width: 100% }` fixed it for me !

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and fixed it. It turned out to be that I was using "left" and "right" classes in my site, and these are actually reserved for Twitter Bootstrap. So, my CSS that said .left { *stuff here* } actually was modifying the carousel. I simply changed my CSS to have a different name, rather than using "left" and "right" I used "float-left" and "float-right", and this fixed it.

Comment: This ended up being my problem too.  Took a long time to get here :)

Comment: damn..exact issue

Answer (score 2):

You need this in your css: `.carousel-inner>.active { width: 100% }`

The reason is that when the carousel advances, the sliding item have `width: 100%`, but for some reason the active item doesn't, and this generates this difference. Maybe this is a bootstrap bug, but i'm not sure.

This was a bit tricky to debug, but changing the value of `transition` speed was helpful :)

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/YLdm8/

**EDIT**

Testing on your site i see that this makes the item smaller. So change the css to this:

```
.carousel-inner>.active, .carousel-inner>.next, .carousel-inner>.prev { 
   width: 102.5%!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was setting the correct  `margin-top: 0px;` in the CSS for `.carousel .item` which did the trick. You might want to tweak this setting and observe it's effect and set it accordingly.